# Knapsack problem with item's weight depending on items selected

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Suppose there are `students[]` with `ages[]`, `subjectsFailed[]` and `subjectsTaken[]`. Suppose Quality Index for each student is `subjectsFailed[i]/subjectsTaken[i]`. I need to select students so that sum of their ages is maxed given that `averageQualityIndex <= x` where

`averageQualityIndex = ∑subjectsFailed[k]/∑subjectsTaken[k]` where k are the students selected.

In normal knapsack problems, the weights are independent. But, in this case, the average weight will depend on the number of students selected till now and their respective weights. Is there a way I can solve this (best possible solution) using knapsack or there is some other way in which we solve this problem (if yes, then what method?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to satisfy the constraint `∑subjectsFailed[k]/∑subjectsTaken[k] <= x`.

Multiplying both sides by `∑subjectsTaken[k]`, this becomes `∑subjectsFailed[k] <= x.∑subjectsTaken[k]`.

Rearranging we find `∑(subjectsFailed[k]-x.subjectsTaken[k]) <= 0` or `∑weights[k] <= 0` where `weights[k] = subjectsFailed[k]-x.subjectsTaken[k]`.

So with this definition of weights it becomes a knapsack problem again.